# How do I force a function to run on any focus change?

Tags: javascript, jsf

My goal is to make sure that the same component always has focus.  The form has one input box and a number of buttons.  The user will scan a barcode (with a scanner emulating a keyboard) and then select a button to activate a function.  I'd like them to be able to scan multiple barcodes without having to click on the input box.  I've got the following javascript that does the dirty work of preparing the inbox for overwriting (currently only if they move focus to the inbox though).

```
function SelectAll(id)
    {
        document.getElementById(id).focus();
        document.getElementById(id).select();
    }
    window.onload = SelectAll('form:scan');
```

I need to allow input to go unimpeded (hence the thought that it should only return focus when focus is lost).  I've already tried adding the function to focus change and button activation events with no success.  Really need to make it page wide it seems as the focus goes somewhere unknown after button activation.

**EDIT**

Appears that doing a focus change on a blur event doesn't work in this case.  It looks like JSF's handlers move the focus after the blur event (and hence focus change request) executes.  Any JSF experts know how to get inside JSF's handlers and tweak them instead of trying to do it with pure javascript?

**EDIT**

I'm part way there.  The reason blur events were being ignored had to do with the whole form being re-rendered instead of just individual components during the AJAX call.  Limiting the update scope makes it work for all components, except the input box itself.  I need the inputbox itself to re-render as it does some validation on input.  If I disable re-rendering of it, it will select on input.  If I enable re-rendering, the select code runs *before* the validated information is put back in.  When the info goes back in, the selection is lost (focus is maintained, but without selection in place we can't immediately scan again, need to click somewhere).

Comment: Would being able to run a script when your target element loses focus (instead of when anything else gains focus) do the job for you?

Comment: It would, but I've had no luck figuring out how to do so.  The code I've written just seems to get ignored if I attach it to a focus lost event.  Do you have any samples/links on how to do so?

Comment: You want the `onblur()` event - it's triggered whenever the control loses focus. If it doesn't look like it's firing then post a jsfiddle for us to play with.

Comment: Hmmm.  Onblur fires, but the focus change doesn't happen (or it happens, but then focus is moved out again afterwards during post processing, hard to tell).

Comment: Currently looking into @BalusC 's phaselistener info...  http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/12/set-focus-in-jsf.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this out pretty sure window load doesn't work in jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jemZT/

```
var scannerID = document.getElementById("scannerID");
function startFocus(){
    scannerID.focus();
}
if(window.addEventListener){
    window.addEventListener('load',startFocus,false); //W3C
}
else{
    window.attachEvent('onload',startFocus); //IE
}
scannerID.addEventListener("blur", function(e){
    e.target.focus();
});​
```

Their are also events for copying and pasting to easily make it when you click a tag it copies it to clipboard might interest you to make the process of copying and pasting codes more simple.

EDIT: confirmed and working I tried this in my browser and it works perfect.

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="scannerID" />
<script type="text/javascript">
var scannerID = document.getElementById("scannerID");
if(window.addEventListener){
    window.addEventListener('load',startFocus,false); //W3C
}else{
    window.attachEvent('onload',startFocus); //IE
}
function startFocus(){
    scannerID.focus();
}
scannerID.addEventListener("blur", function(e){
    e.target.focus();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, it works in jsfiddle, but doesn't work on my page.  Curious.  JSF must have some code that eats that functionality.

Comment: Which browser are you testing it in? It does the opposite for me doesn't work in jsfiddle but works on page.

Comment: Internet Explorer.  Note that I'm running this javascript inside of a JSF app, NOT just raw HTML.  I'm thinking JSF has it's own handlers that are interfering with these.